# Оконные приложения на чистом C

Tags: c

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли на чистом C написать оконное приложение? Если да, то какие библиотеки для этого существуют? Меня интересует с помощью каких инструментов отрисовывается GUI в Windows или в Linux или в любой другой ОС. То есть, при разработке этих ОС, GUI писался с нуля? Или любое приложение, написанное на C, но с оконным интерфейсом. Под чистым C, я имею в виду чистый C без сторонних библиотек, а только встроенные, типа stdlib или stdio. В учебниках по C рассказывается только о том как написать консольное приложение и ничего об оконных. Если что не правильно, пожалуйста, поправьте меня.

Comment: WinApi например =) а вообще вопрос требует правки.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018850/cross-platform-c-library-for-gui-apps

Comment: Если графика&игры, то SDL2.

Comment: что такое "чистый C"?

Comment: @Croessmah словосочетание "чистый С" используют для акцентирования на отсутствии "плюсов". Без этого кто-нибудь сразу же предложил бы Qt.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev присутствие плюсов в C невозможно в принципе, т.к. тогда получится язык C++.

Comment: @Croessmah не все это понимают, к сожалению. Многие воспринимают C++ не как отдельный язык, а как дополнительные возможности C. Поэтому иногда приходится расставлять акценты.

Comment: xorg-x11-devel , libx11-dev

Comment: Не мучаетесь вопросами, выберите winapi если целевая платформа win, там все просто и лаконично, и выходной файл будет занимать килобайт 100 :) как в старое доброе время. Для линукса смотреть X11, оно там из коробки, но подводных камней там... Мультиплатформенный wxWidget, наверно самое оптимальное, но это С++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GTK+, Tk, IUP, Nuklear, libui.